# jQuery if checkbox "A" is checked from list 1, check "A" on list 2

Tags: jquery, checkbox, matching

I have a main list of checkboxes:

```
<div id="main_list">
<input name="main_list[]" class="main-checkbox" value="Austin" checked="" type="checkbox">
<input name="main_list[]" class="main-checkbox" value="San Antonio" checked="" type="checkbox">
<input name="main_list[]" class="main-checkbox" value="El Paso" checked="" type="checkbox">
</div>
```

I would like to match the two lists, for example if "Austin" is checked on main list, check on single list.

```
<div id="single_list">
<input name="checkbox_list[]" class="list-checkbox" value="Austin" type="checkbox">
<input name="checkbox_list[]" class="list-checkbox" value="Houston" type="checkbox">
<input name="checkbox_list[]" class="list-checkbox" value="Dallas" type="checkbox">
</div>
```

How can I accomplish it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the jQuery selector on the input's value.

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('input[value="' + value + '"]').prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        $('input[value="' + value + '"]').prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

[Demo Here](https://jsfiddle.net/1fqqk60x/)

Comment: ahh you win, my vote I didnt create an else or a demo

Comment: No problem, glad to help out!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a listener that changes the corresponding list-checkbox when a main-checkbox is changed:

```
$('.main-checkbox').on('change', function(){
    $('.list-checkbox[value=' + $(this).val() + ']').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
});
```

This will loop through each at load of the page to ensure the correct list-checkboxes are checked in relation to their main-checkbox partner. Not really necessary if you are coding static pages, but if the main-checkboxes are dynamic and the list-checkboxes are static, you could add this in your load function:

```
$('.main-checkbox').each(function(){
  $('.list-checkbox[value=' + $(this).val() + ']').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
});
```

Edit: Here's a fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/jkw6top4/

Comment: Thanks for your help! very useful